# What is the volume of a solid S obtained when a region R is rotated about the line y=2x?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, centroid, solid-of-revolution

[Alternate method using multivar also displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bFOY.png)

Let R be the region in the first quadrant bounded by the line $y=2x$, the curve $y=sin(x)$, and the line $l$ that is perpendicular to $y=2x$ and goes through the point ($\frac{\pi}2{}$,$1$). Find the volume of the solid $S$ obtained when $R$ is rotated $360$ degrees around the line $y=2x$. Also, find the surface area of $S$ including the circular base swept out by $l$.

I tried to use Pappus' Theorem to find the volume using the volume is equal to the area I found the area setting up two different integrals finding the area to equal $0.60217$. I then found the centroid coordinates at $(.8409, .7756)$ and the distance to equal 0.164 and the circumference the centroid travels to then equal $1.03195$ and the only part I am sure of is the arc length is $1.9101$.

Obviously $1.03195$ x $0.60217$ $\neq$ $2.74$ and $1.03195$ x $1.9101$ $\neq$ $7.5$ that wolfram alpha found. Can someone help me realize my mistake? I think the error is the centroid location or centroid distance traveled. A centroid radius of around $0.62$ makes the math work out perfectly.

The Wolfram Alpha solution:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rotate+the+region+between+2x+and+sin+x+with+0%3Cx%3Cpi%2F2+around+y%3D2x

[Image of the question in detail to eliminate confusion][2]

i.stack.imgur.com/Q93OA.png

I don't have enough reputation just add an https:// before the i.stack

Comment: Do you want only the portion of $R$ whose projection onto the $x$-axis is the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$? Or do you want to include the part for $x>\frac{\pi}{2}$ between the sine graph and the line perpendicular to $y=2x$.

Comment: $(\pi * \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{1}{5}}$  $(2x-sinx)^2)$  +  $\pi * \int_{\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{1}{5}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\frac{-1}{2}x + \frac{\pi}{4} +1 -sinx)^2 $ You computed it?

Comment: I updated the question to minimize confusion of what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Half a spinning top!

To use Pappus' theorem, you need to find the coordinates of several points in this problem.  As describing the computation of all that can be quite verbose, here is a figure to set things up and am providing the coordinates I got -  we can discuss if you got something different
[image]
length of sine curve:
$$S=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}dx\\
x_L=\frac{1}{S}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}dx\\
y_L=\frac{1}{S}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin x\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}dx
$$
Area to be rotated:
$$A=\int_0^{X_M} (2x-\sin x) dx + \int_{x_M}^\frac{\pi}{2}(\frac{-x}{2}+1+\frac{\pi}{4}-\sin x) dx\\
=0.2657+0.2845=0.5502
$$
Centroid:
$$A \times x_C=\int_0^{X_M} x(2x-\sin x) dx + \int_{x_M}^\frac{\pi}{2}x (\frac{-x}{2}+1+\frac{\pi}{4}-\sin x) dx\\
2A \times y_C=\int_0^{X_M} (2x)^2-\sin^2 x) dx + \int_{x_M}^\frac{\pi}{2} \left[(\frac{-x}{2}+1+\frac{\pi}{4})^2-\sin^2 x \right] dx
$$
Results:
$$M=(x_m,y_m)=\left(\frac{4+\pi}{10},\frac{4+\pi}{5}\right)\\
R=(\frac{\pi}{2},1)\\
L=(0.7317,0.6009)\\
C=(0.7359,0.8870)\\
d_C=0.2615\\
d_L=0.3857\\
d_R=0.9577\\
A=0.5501\\
S=1.9101
$$

where $A$ is the total area (pink+green) and $S$ is the length of the $\sin$ curve from the origin to R.  From here, the volume is $$V=2\pi d_CA=0.9041\\
SA=2\pi d_L S + \pi d_R^2=7.5106$$

Note: This problem is straightforward in principle.  Most of the work here is only because of the tilted axis of rotation. I usually avoid using the Pappus rule and prefer to do integration directly.  However, in this case, it seems that it's not easy to get a closed form (impossible so far for me) for the sine curve if you do a coordinate transformation to make the axis of rotation the vertical axis of the coordinate system.  Hence, we need to resort to Pappus.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm not sure how to upload these amazing pictures but I got the same thing for the most part. My problem was that my values did not match up with those given via the parametric calculus listed in Wolfram Alpha. I think you could also do it with Jacobians and via that method, I get the same volume as Wolfram Alpha lists but my teacher prohibits that. Your use of Pappus' Theorem worked far better than mine I didn't get the surface area at all. I love the community here on stack exchange. Was there an error in the calculations for volume or is the method flawed?

Comment: Glad you liked it. If helpful, please upvote and accept the answer.  Volume: I am not sure what went wrong. Our values are different for A as well as the centroid. That's why I provided each integral separately so that you can spot where the difference is.  If you wish to ask for the numerical values of any particular integral, I still have them in my notebook and can give it.

Comment: Of course, if you are using a different way, then a term by term comparison is not possible. Btw, what is the Jacobian method to this problem? Could you perhaps post a link with an example?

Comment: I did but I don't have enough reputation. I vaguely recall the method from five years ago in multivariable calc I'm actually trying to help a friend who is doing this question in an introductory course. I'll update the question to show what I tried with the other method because I don't know how to add an image in a comment.

Comment: I think you could also make y=2x the new y-axis by rewriting everything in parametric coordinates. I also saw a different method online that I never learned in class that's also linked below. It's times like this I remember why I like discrete math more...

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666237/how-to-calculate-the-volume-of-revolution-without-the-shell-method-or-the-disk-m

http://www.emathhelp.net/notes/calculus-2/applications-of-integrals/volume-of-solid-of-revolution-about-slant-line/

Comment: Ha, no worries.  Hopefully, you'll soon have more reputation to be able to do all that.  Btw, that method of slicing in the link you sent is cool.  I just did the volume by that method and see that it gives the same volume as the one I posted in the answer.  As form making y=2x the new axis by a coordinate transform, as I mentioned in my note, that works only for some nice function, not for this one.

Comment: Although you need 15 reputation to be able to upvote, as a question-asker, you can accept an right away without needing more reputation points.   In fact, accepting is also a way to gain a few reputation points, which will then unlock other privileges.  (acceptance by clicking the check mark / tick mark to the left of the answer) .  https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer